# how to limit the found matches on perl using regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I come to ask for your aid after a lot of research on this matter:

I'm trying to limit the repetition of the substitutions that a Perl regex does on a big text. 
I've searched in Google and found that the format is {2,3}  (min, max) however this seems to be for a different way that the syntax I'm using.

```
$replaced=~s/$var/$var2/g; # replaces all ocurrences
$replaced=~s/$var/$var2/;  # replaces only first one
```

my non optimal solution:

```
for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){

    $replaced=~s/$var/$var2/;
}
```

What I have tried:

```
$replaced=~s/$var/$var2/{8};
$replaced=~s/$var/$var2{8}/;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

edit: 
OK so pretty much there has to be a loop involved huh.. isn't that weird that there is not a built in parameter to limit it??

Comment: why do you think your solution is not optimal?

Comment: The for loop is more or less how I would do it.

Comment: well what if im parsing a 100mb file and the ocurrences are on the second half of the block, i will be reading the first 50mb everytime , if this can be limited it will be just one read

Comment: If you know that ... don't run the regex against the first 50mb

Comment: it was just an example, datasets are generated and the ocurrences could be anywhere in the file

Comment: A bit more Perl-ish loop would be something like: $i=8;while ($i--) .

Comment: @James_R_Ferguson - why is that Perl-ish?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera : IMO shorter.

Comment: An even more perlish loop would be `for (1..8)`.

Comment: @James_R_Ferguson : It is not very Perlish to use a temp var (`$i`) when one can do without (Ven'Tatsu suggested `for (1..8)`).

Comment: @Zaid: Yes, you're right; I yield.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers with `\G` are probably the most practical way to do what you want, but just for fun or edification or whatever, here is another way (requiring perl 5.10 or higher), using code assertions and the [backtracking control verbs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlre#Special_Backtracking_Control_Verbs) `(*COMMIT)` and `(*FAIL)`:

```
my $str = "Bananas in pajamas are coming down the stairs";
my $limit = 3;
my $count;

$str =~ s/(*COMMIT)(?(?{ $count++ >= 3 })(*FAIL))a/A/g;
say $str;
```

which leaves the text "BAnAnAs in Pajamas are coming down the stairs" in `$str` — only the first three "a"s were affected and it stops scanning the string for more matches after the third.

Comment: I usually put the counter in the replacement portion.

Comment: @tchrist I don't follow. Care to explain? Also, answer my mail re: casefolding! ;)

Comment: `s/(a)/$count++ < 3 ? "A" : $1/ge`

Comment: @tchrist Ah, I see. Yeah, that works, but doesn't stop matching, which might matter if you have a huge pile of data and/or your pattern is expensive.

Comment: @tchrist I'm the guy whose case-folding module khw was mailing you about. I followed up directly to you via email.

Comment: I have a funny mail setup.  That means you are in some easy-to-miss place. I'll look around.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4923/discussion-between-hobbs-and-tchrist)

Comment: @hobbs Would this solution parse the whole string on ever iteration or would it continue where the last match left off?

Comment: @Rafael.IT it goes through the string once, and stops after the third match.

Comment: @hobbs using your method gives an error, this works tho:
s/(a)/$count++ < 3 ? "A" : $1/ge

Comment: @tchrist since your answer worked the best if  you want to go ahead and post it as answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @Rafael.IT amended my answer to mention that it requires perl 5.10 or better.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fluent in Perl, but I believe you want to use the "`\G` Assertion" ([more info here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm)), which will continue searching for a new match at the place the previous match left off:

```
for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){

    $replaced=~s/\G$var/$var2/;
}
```

I'm not positive whether it is in fact more efficient, but it certainly seems like that's what it's intended for...

Comment: The `$i` variable is doing nothing here. A more elegant way to write this is `s/\G$var/$var2/ for 1 .. 8;`

Comment: @Zaid: but you cannot ommit `$replaced=~` in this case, because `for 1 .. 8` sets `$_`.

Comment: Correct, that should start with `$replaced =~ `

Answer (score 1):

Answer: http://codenode.com/2010/06/24/single-pass-replace-with-perl-regex-g-anchor/

Excerpt with modification for counter:

```
my $cnt = 0;
if ( $query =~ m/\bORDER BY /gi ) {
   while ($query =~ s/\G(.+?)\s+ASC/$1/gmsi && pos $query) {
       $cnt++; last if $cnt >= 8;
   }
}
```